# Pickling __setstate__ and __getstate__ not invoking on class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I have a class that is part of multiple inheritance, and the `__getstate__` and the `__setstate__` functions never get called on the child class.

```
class BaseGeometery(dict):
    pass

@add_metaclass(GeometryFactory)
class Geometry(BaseGeometry): 
    pass

class Point(Geometry): 
    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        # initialize and call super()
        pass 

    def __setstate_(self, d):
          print(d)

    def __getstate__(self):
         print('in get state')
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `def __getstate__(self):`, should return something.

Read: [handling-stateful-objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#handling-stateful-objects)

Comment: Thanks you for the answer.  I was missing the return.