# How to serializing and de-serializing a PyQt Widget?

Tags: python, pyqt

Python version: 3.5

PyQt version: 5.6.0

OS :Windows 10

I have a PyQt project, and i want save a PYQT-tablewidget on disk(include items data),i can dump the tablewidget and save to be a file.But when load the file, i can't use that widget. when i load the `pkl_file`, it tell us "super-class **init**() of type QTableWidget was never called".

```
    def slot1(self):
        output = open('data.pkl', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(self.tableWidget, output)
        output.close()

    def slot2(self):
        pkl_file = open('data.pkl', 'rb')
        data1 = pickle.load(pkl_file)
        try:
            # super-class __init__() of type QTableWidget was never called
            print('text: ',data1.item(0, 0).text())
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        pkl_file.close()
```

full code is in here :http://codepad.org/UG0p7fKQ

Comment: I don't think you can simply use pickle to dump the whole TableWidget object. The QTableWidget is essentially a QTableView with a default QAbstractTableModel in the background. To save your data you will have to extract it from the model and pickle it. Vize-versa for loading the data.

Comment: Read about handling-stateful-objects : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718080/pickling-setstate-and-getstate-not-invoking-on-class/43719022?noredirect=1#comment74484963_43719022

Comment: [PyQt does not support pickling wdgets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22889876/984421).